# Why isn't this string.match consistently working?

Tags: arrays, regex, string, lua, lua-patterns

I am writing an addon for the game World of Warcraft (WoW). It uses lua, with a library of functions specific to the game. I am checking whether a substring can be found in a string. The substring in question is given by the variable ItemType, which in this case contains the string `"Two-Handed Swords"`. The string in which I am checking is given by a table entry and contains `"One-Handed Axes, One-Handed Swords, Two-Handed Axes, Two-Handed Swords, Bows, Crossbows, Guns, Wands, Mail, Plate, Shields"`. The problem is that when I run the function on the item in question, it's acting as if the item doesn't match.

The full code is as follows

```
local NotUsableItemsTable = {
    "Wands",
    "Daggers, Fist Weapons, Staves, Bows, Crossbows, Guns, Wands",
    "One-Handed Maces, Two-Handed Maces, Wands, Plate, Shields",
    "Polearms, Staves, Two-Handed Axes, Two-Handed Maces, Two-Handed Swords, Wands, Mail, Plate, Shields",
    "Fist Weapons, One-Handed Axes, One-Handed Swords, Polearms, Two-Handed Axes, Two-Handed Maces, Two-Handed Swords, Bows, Crossbows, Guns, Leather, Mail, Plate, Shields",
    "Daggers, Fist Weapons, Staves, Bows, Crossbows, Guns, Wands, Shields",
    "One-Handed Swords, Polearms, Two-Handed Swords, Bows, Crossbows, Guns, Wands, Plate",
    "Fist Weapons, One-Handed Axes, One-Handed Maces, Polearms, Two-Handed Axes, Two-Handed Maces, Two-Handed Swords, Bows, Crossbows, Guns, Leather, Mail, Plate, Shields",
    "Fist Weapons, One-Handed Axes, One-Handed Maces, Polearms, Two-Handed Axes, Two-Handed Maces, Two-Handed Swords, Bows Crossbows, Guns, Leather, Mail, Plate, Shields",
    "Placeholder String: There is no class corresponding to index 10.",
    "One-Handed Axes, One-Handed Swords, Two-Handed Axes, Two-Handed Swords, Bows, Crossbows, Guns, Wands, Mail, Plate, Shields"
}

function IsItemUseableByPlayer(itemID)
    if itemID == nil then return nil end
    local ClassInfo = {UnitClass("player")}
    local NotUsableItemsString = NotUsableItemsTable[ClassInfo[3]]
    local ItemInfo = {GetItemInfo(itemID)}
    local ItemType = ItemInfo[7]
    if string.match(NotUsableItemsString, ItemType) then
        return true
    else
        return false
    end
end
```

`UnitClass("player")` returns `{ "Druid", "DRUID", 11 }` in this case.
`ItemType` i.e. `ItemInfo[7]` returns `"Two-Handed Swords"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`-` is a magic character in Lua pattern matching. You need to escape it with a `%`.

You can also use `string.find`, which can be asked to do plain matching.

Comment: damn, beat me by seconds :D

Comment: Where would I escape it? The string in `NotUseableItemsTable`? (I ask because `ItemType` is returned by the game and I can't think of any way to bypass its formatting.

Comment: Yes, you would have to escape ItemType. However, as @lhf noted, you can also use string.find: `if string.find(NotUsableItemsString, ItemType, 1, true) then`, where `1` indicates the index where to start and `true` tells the function to treat the second parameter as a search string rather than a search pattern.

Comment: That cracked it. Thanks, both of you!

Answer (score 0):

Your strings contain characters with special meaning in Lua patterns, in this case the `-`. You have to escape it with `%`.